# How to save state of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Please help me, how can I save state of `UICollectionViewCell`. For example: I have cells with `UIWebView` and when I `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returned wrong cell, not for this `indexPath` and after it `UIWebView` content will reloaded for correct `indexPath` with twitches. Thanks!

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NewsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NEWS_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell.isShowed) {  // I just added boolean property
        cell.isShowed = YES;

        /*** some init actions ***/
    }

    return cell;
}
```

If I use this method, cells with `cell.isShowed == YES` return on wrong `indexPath`. But if I not use `cell.isShowed` content of UIWebView will reloaded in every showing cell
Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Have you used the correct indexPath?

Comment: Yes, I just use indexPath from  - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: What do you mean by 'not for this indexPath'? Can you paste your code? I need more code to see what's your problem.

Comment: "return on wrong indexPath" means the cell is successfully shown but on the wrong row?

Comment: So, sunkehappy, do you have any ideas about that? :)

Answer (score 0):

See what Apple's [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say:

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

But `UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. So you need to redesign your architecture.

Comment: `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` ?